# Recommenderlab: Predict by UBCF binary rating matrix

Tags: r, statistics, collaborative-filtering, cross-product, recommenderlab

In recommenderlab R package, on predicting `UBCF` based on binary rating matrix, why does the script do crossprod between knn (`k` nearest neighbors) similarities and new input binary ratings for the items? I'm writing a study and I wondering why is it a good way.

The results of the predict were very good on market basket recommendation, an I'm confused on `crossprod` useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/recommenderlab/vignettes/recommenderlab.pdf), in `UBCF` the missing ratings are predicted as aggregate ratings of the similar (neighboring) users.

Once the users in the neighborhood are found, their ratings are aggregated to form the predicted rating for the active user `u_a` (as shown below).

- The easiest form is to just average the ratings in the neighborhood.
- Better version if to compute weighted average of the neighborhood ratings, where the weights are the similarity of a neighboring user with the active user.

[image]

Now, `crossprod()` is used for computing the weighted average (can be used to compute simple average too, when weights are equal). Given matrices `x`, `y`, the matrix crossproduct is computed by `crossprod()` as `t(x) %*% y` or `t(y) %*% x` (from [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/crossprod)).

Take the following example from the documentation, as shown in the next figure:

[image]

Here, u_1, u_2 and u_4 are neighboring users for the active user u_a, for which ratings for 4 items are missing. Let's see how `crossprod()` can be used to compute the missing ratings with simple and weighted averages of ratings of the neighboring users, respectively (using the code similar to the [original implementation](https://github.com/mhahsler/recommenderlab/blob/master/R/RECOM_UBCF.R)).

```
r_neighbors <- matrix(c(NA, 4.0, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, NA, NA,
                       3.0, NA, NA, NA, 5.0, 1.0, NA, NA,
                       4.0, NA, NA, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 4.0), nrow=3, byrow=T)

u_a <- matrix(c(NA,NA,4.0,3.0,NA,1.0,NA,5.0), nrow=1)

# simple average of neighbor ratings, with all weights equal to 1
s_uk <- matrix(rep(1, 3), ncol=1)
r_a <- as(crossprod(replace(r_neighbors, is.na(r_neighbors), 0), s_uk), "matrix") /
          as(crossprod(!is.na(r_neighbors), s_uk), "matrix")
u_a[is.na(u_a)] <- r_a[is.na(u_a)]
u_a
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]     [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# [1,]  3.5    4    4    3 2.333333    1    2    5
```

The above ratings match exactly with the ones computed in the figure. Also, you can reproduce the same prediction results for the new user `u_a` with `recommenderlab`'s `predict()`, as shown below:

```
library(recommenderlab)
u_a <- matrix(c(NA,NA,4.0,3.0,NA,1.0,NA,5.0), nrow=1)
rec <- Recommender(as(r_neighbors, "realRatingMatrix"), method = "UBCF", 
                   param=list(nn=3, normalize=NULL, weighted=FALSE))
pred <- as(predict(rec, newdata=as(u_a, "realRatingMatrix"), type="ratings"), "matrix")
u_a[is.na(u_a)] <- pred[is.na(u_a)]
u_a
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]     [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# [1,]  3.5    4    4    3 2.333333    1    2    5
```

If you want to use-user similarity-based weights, the same code will do the job, with similarity weights this time,

```
u_a <- matrix(c(NA,NA,4.0,3.0,NA,1.0,NA,5.0), nrow=1)
s_uk <- matrix(c(0.3, 1.0, 0.3), ncol=1)
r_a <- as(crossprod(replace(r_neighbors, is.na(r_neighbors), 0), s_uk), "matrix") /
          as(crossprod(!is.na(r_neighbors), s_uk), "matrix")
u_a[is.na(u_a)] <- r_a[is.na(u_a)]
u_a
#          [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# [1,] 3.230769    4    4    3  3.5    1    2    5
```

Comment: As in recommenderlab predict function: 

ratings <- t(sapply(1:nrow(newdata), FUN = function(i) {
      r_neighbors <- as(model$data[neighbors[[i]]], "dgCMatrix")
      drop(as(crossprod(r_neighbors, s_uk[, i]), "matrix"))/colSums(!dropNAis.na(r_neighbors))
    }))

Here we have colSums(!dropNAis.na(r_neighbors)). That means, in binary rating, the ocurrences of an item in the k nearest neighbors for each item.

But I think you answer says that this should be the aggregated user similarities of the knn.
And that makes sense to me. So why is the script implemented on that way?

Comment: It's for dropping the `NA` ratings and to only consider the ratings of the NN users who have non-`NA` ratings

Comment: Yes, in the code it is the sum of 1's ratings (non-NA).

But I think it should be the sum of NN similarities, according to the weighted formula in the documentation.

It seems like there's something I'm not quite grasping or interpreting correctly.

Comment: for a given user and an item (the user has not yet rated),  the predicted rating (for the item) is computed as weighted average of the NN ratings for the item, but you must get rid of the NNs who have not rated the item yet (i.e., have `NA` ratings for the item).

Comment: @John Danson added a piece of code with `recommenderlab`'s `predict()`  function (note the `params` list passed) that eactly matches the prediction output for the unweighted case. For the weighted case you can reproduce the output too, similar to the one with `recommenderlab`, but you need to input the right user-user similarity (e.g., `cosine`) as `s_uk`, to be used as weights

Comment: It's sum of 1 ratings when it's unweighted otherwise it's weighted by user-user similarities computed in `s_uk` when the condition `model$wieghted` is `TRUE`, implemented with `crosspeod()`, check the source code carefully

Comment: The unweighted: `ratings <- t(sapply(1:nrow(newdata), FUN = function(i) {
      colCounts(model$data[neighbors[[i]]])` .... but in weighted: `ratings <- t(sapply(1:nrow(newdata), FUN = function(i) {
      r_neighbors <- as(model$data[neighbors[[i]]], "dgCMatrix")
      drop(as(crossprod(r_neighbors, s_uk[, i]), "matrix"))/colSums(!dropNAis.na(r_neighbors))` .   What I would like to be the denominator is what you told me in your first answer: `as(crossprod(!is.na(r_neighbors), s_uk), "matrix")` .

Comment: But suppose an item is selected by 8 of 10 NN. Its denominator is 8, the sum of all non-NA ratings.

Or it could be the sum of user similarities for the 8 NN.

Whats the correct denominator?

Comment: There is nothing universally correct in machine learning I guess, it depends upon the scenario and usecase. The `recommenderlab` gives you both unweighted and similarity-weighted options to compute the average ratings from the neighbors (as in the example, you can specify your choice using the `weighted` boolean parameter in the `params` list ). I think when the cold-start period is over, the weighted average should work better, since you have enough data to compute the user-user similarity more reliably. Also, the example uses real rating matrix, but the same works for binary rating matrix.

Comment: So I guess there's two weighted ways in this case. Rating mean weighted by similarities and similarity mean weighted by ratings.